# How to ban Alt+Tab hot keys in Windows system?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

How to ban <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> hot keys in Windows system?

How to ban the hot key?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226359

Comment: Note that you also need to disable Win+Tab, Win+Number, Win+T, Win+Everything, eventually, the Windows key itself and a number of other key combinations too. And even that will not prevent anyone from hitting Ctrl+Alt+Del and breaking out of your application. So why bother?

Comment: @Joey, `NoWinKeys` has no effect on Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Alt+Delete, Ctrl+Shift+Esc, Win+L, or Win+U; those are handled differently and need a keyboard hook to affect (even then…)